# displaying wordpress post on another site

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, posts

I'm currently trying to find the best way to display posts saved in Wordpress on another site.

I've found various options so far but the problem I'm getting which I can't seem to find any answers on is when the post is displayed, none of the formatting is kept, for example, in the main content of a post, the paragraphs, bullet points and font stylings aren't displayed. Also if I add an image to the post that also appears to be left out.

I'm hoping the best way will be PHP and MySQL, but looking throught the Wordpress files I'm unsure how they are structured. The Wordpress directory will be located in the same directory of my site (e.g mysite/wordpress)

This maybe something many other people have asked but I'm struggling to find the correct terminology inorder to search for the answer.

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to connect directly to the blog database. You can simply create a new file in your Wordpress directory and include the `wp-blog-header.php` file:

**Example:**

```
<?php
require('./wordpress/wp-blog-header.php'); // change this to fit your path
?>
<p>Recent Posts:</p>
<ul>
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<li><?php the_title(); ?> </li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

Hope that helps!